# Contextual filter : Override Title

Tags: views

The content architecture of the site which I am working on is something like:-

1. Song - Content type
2. Genre - Vocabulory

Song has an entity reference field which points to the terms in "Genre" vocabulary.

**Genre** field is added in the view which lists **Songs** content.
The field result has been rewritten as link which points to the URL pattern : `songs/<genre-name>` (`[field-genre]` was used).

The path `songs/%` is a separate view page, which is supposed to take the "genre name" as contextual filter, and show songs of that particular genre.

[image: Snapshot]
Here the url gets the taxonomy term name but the title gives %2 instead of the name

[image: Snapshot]
Override title is %2

[image]

The view is working fine but I am not able to replace the title.

Answer (score 0):

I tried %1 in the override title and it worked.

Comment: You have to use %1 as views will consider form arg(0) is "song-tracks" and arg(1) is "Romantic"